# Select statement that returns data from the period of 300 minutes from the current time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table that contains a row with flight departure times in 'datetime' format and I need to create a select statement that returns all the flight times with a departure in the next 300 minutes from the current time.

I used this statement and it showed me times from the past too along with the ones in the next 300 minutes.

```
SELECT [Departure date]
FROM Tickets                                
WHERE datepart(day, [Departure date]) >= datepart(Day, getdate())     
AND datepart(day, [Departure date]) <= datepart(Day, getdate()+(300/24/24))
```

Comment: Hint:  `dateadd(300, minute, getdate())`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for telling us, but what is your question? What's stopping you from achieving your goal? What have *you* tried to get the results you want? Why didn't it work?

Comment: You want to filter by departures greater than 'now' and less than 300 minutes from 'now'.  GETDATE() gets you now - DATEADD gets you 300 minutes from now.

Comment: Why are you only comparing the date component? You need to include the time for a 300 min window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Jeff's comment you want to create a window from now to +300 minutes which you do as follows

```
-- >= now
WHERE [Departure date] >= GETDATE()
-- < 300 minutes (you might use <= depending on your exact use case
AND [Departure date] < DATEADD(minute, 300, GETDATE())
```